# uploading file using Restassured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I would like to upload a file using Java and the RestAssured library. Does anyone know how i can use this library to upload a file to a field?

When using Postman, i just make the call to the endpoint and add in the Body section key=upload and value has a "Choose files" button.

How can i upload a file to a field using Restassured? I already have methods that make the body of the request and set all parameters for it, like here:

```
public CustomizationSetClientField(String clientId, String fieldSetName, String version, String fieldName, String name, String type, String value, String language, String role){
        this.body.put("name", name);
        this.body.put("type", type);
        this.body.put("value", value);

        this.url = Config.getByName("customization_url");
        this.pathTemplate = Config.getByName("customization_set_client_field");
        this.path = Utils.createPath(pathTemplate, clientId, fieldSetName, version, fieldName);
        this.role = role;


    }
```

Now this is for setting fields, but i have no idea how to use Restassured with uploads, can you please show me how?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for [multipart file uploads](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#multi-part-form-data). For example:

```
given().
        multiPart("file", new File("/path/to/file")).
when().
        post("/upload");
```

Comment: I believe multiPart(new File("/path/to/file")) would also work.

Comment: Depends on the control name. If it's "file" then it would work as you say.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file using REST API it require 'Content-Type' as 'multipart/form-data'.
Now you need to understand with the developer that are they allowing to directly passing the file to API or need to convert the file content to Byte Array.

If require to convert into byte then you can use the below code

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(filePath));
RestAssured.given().headers(headers).body(fileContent ).post(url);
```

else you can try directly with the code shared by Johan in another comment.